# How to merge multicolors in div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a code to merge the given number of colors in div to form a legend.
I have referred  the following [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RSyCM/) code.

```
$.each(Array(50), function() {
    $("<div>").appendTo(document.body);
});

var divs = $('div'),
    len = divs.length;

var targ_R = 227,
    targ_G = 151,
    targ_B = 4,

    inc_R = (255 - targ_R) / len,
    inc_G = (255 - targ_G) / len,
    inc_B = (255 - targ_B) / len;

divs.css("backgroundColor", function(i, curr) {
    return "#" +
        toHex(255 - (i * inc_R)) +
        toHex(255 - (i * inc_G)) +
        toHex(255 - (i * inc_B));
});

function toHex(n) {
    var h = (~~n).toString(16);
    if (h.length < 2)
        h = "0" + h;
    return h;
}
```

But its just for a single color.I need to use more than one color here.
Expected output is  [image]

Anyone please help me to do tis.

Comment: Can you provide an image of the expected output?

Comment: you'd be better off using a canvas

Comment: But if we use canvas is it possible to select a particular color??

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/M9MYx/1/

```
count = 100;

colors = [
  [227, 151, 4 ],
  [ 33, 120, 70]
];

$.each(colors, function(i){
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var color = '#';

    $.each(this, function(idx, val){
      color += toHex(inv(inc(val), i));
    });

    $('<div>')
      .css('background', color)
      .appendTo(document.body)
    ;//$div
  }
});

function inc(val){
  return (255 - val) / count;
}

function inv(val, i){
  return 255 - (i * val);
}

function toHex(n) {
  var h = (~~n).toString(16);
  if (h.length < 2) h = "0" + h;
  return h;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.But I need divs from 101 with the color of Golden yellow[227, 151, 4 ],which is 100th div color to green [33, 120, 70] and not from white to Green